# How to change value of a view dynamically based on server response?

Tags: java, android, notifications, signalr

Am using SignalR server for backend communication.It's request and response are based on handlers.Am using ArrayAdapter to set dynamic childviews in Grid.How can i dynamically update the values of the views inside ArrayAdapter.

SignalR Request:

```
signalRproxy.invoke(Name of Server Method to send request, parameter).done(new Action<Void>() 
{
    @Override
    public void run(Void obj) throws Exception 
    {

    }
});
}
```

SignalR Response:

```
signalRproxy.on(Name of Client Method to send response, new SubscriptionHandler1<String>()
{
    @Override
    public void run(String responseString) 
    {

    }

}, String.class);
```

In between if i try to call any user defined method inside method of server response.it leads to crash.Could any one help me to fix this.

Comment: u need to write syncronize method while updating ui and using arraylist u can dynamicall add and remove data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all.I've found a solution to get the data dynamically from SignalR serve response using a handler class.

```
Handler handle = new Handler();
    static String signalRres;

    signalRproxy.on(Name of Client Method to send response, new SubscriptionHandler1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void run(String responseString) {
            signalRres = responseString;
            handle.post(run);
        }

    }, String.class);


    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("Running", "Runnable Data" + signalRres);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your `ArrayList<Item> mArrayList;` (add, remove, update, clear items...) and then call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on your adapter.